# onChange event added to watch method

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync

I see from the [browsersync docs](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/) that on the watch method you can add two events

```
gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

What's the difference between the two? Is not `watch` automatically linked to any change event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Proper answer**

```
gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
```

Instructs gulp to run defined task `sass` every time changes are detected on selected subset of files. If you haven't passed any [options](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch#options), by default it will watch for `add`, `change`, `unlink` events.

In above code, any addition, deletion or change in `*.scss` files under `app/scss` directory will cause `sass` task to be executed.

```
gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

Since `gulp.watch()` [returns](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch#returns) a `chokidar` instance, you can fine-tune events you will be responding to by using `.on('event', eventHandler)` method ([examples](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch#chokidar-instance)).

It means, in this example `browserSync.reload` will be only called if any of `*.html` files has *changed* in `app/` directory. In case of adding new file, or deleting existing one, it will not reload the browser.

**Old answer, probably not really helpful**

Basically, each `gulp.watch()` is watching for changes in different places/files, that's why there are two of them (for example to prevent running sass compiler against html files).

First one is checking if any of `*.scss` files have changed, then runs gulp task `sass` that will process changed scss files into css. That task is defined with
`gulp.task('sass', function() {/* code from example */})`.

Second one is checking for any `.html` files change, and when it's changed, it runs callback function `browserSync.reload` to reflect changes in browser.

Comment: You've just explained that code which is obvious. The OP asked why gulp has two ways of handling the change (via another task and via the change event), and asked what is the difference between these two ways of handling the change, regardless of what to do about the change.

Comment: @Unicornist - updated the answer. How did you manage to dig it out after over three years since posting it?:)

Comment: Great! Just came across with the same problem the OP had.